# loading custom functions in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I saved this function so I can reuse it many Jupyter Notebooks with out having to define every time for each notebook.

```
def strip_accents(s):
    return ''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s)
              if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn')
```

I can import it fine to my Jupyter Notebook, but it wont work and I get this error.

> NameError: name 'unicodedata' is not defined

even though I have imported unicodedata in the notebook.  Functions that don't rely on an outside module work fine.  My question is how I can load my functions that rely on outside modules so that they run.

Comment: Did you import the unicodedata in the file that contains strip_accents(s)?

Comment: Yes I imported it in the file

Comment: try running the following command in your jupyter notebook.
!pip3 install unicodedata

Comment: I get this error ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement unicodedata (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for unicodedata

Comment: my apologies the actual code is !pip3 install unicodedata2

Comment: it installed correctly. but still gives the same error.